# How to $unwind a collection inside a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "Course" with this structure:

```
{ 
  Lessons: [ 
  {
     Title: 'xxx',
     Contents: [ 
     {
       Title: 'yyy',
     },
     ...
     ]
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the list of Titles of all Contents using MongoDB's aggregation pipeline?

I managed to $unwind all contents this way:

```
db.Course.aggregate( { $unwind : '$Lessons' }, { $unwind : '$Lessons.Contents' } )
```

But I can't manage to filter only the Titles within each Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. If I got your requirement right you just need to add a projection:

```
db.Course.aggregate( 
  { $unwind : "$Lessons" }, 
  { $unwind : "$Lessons.Contents" }, 
  { $project: { _id: 0, test: "$Lessons.Contents.Title" } } 
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I thought I had to reference the element inside the array somehow. Never occurred to me that $Lessons.Contents.Title was valid.

Comment: I tried to find a good reference about this field path syntax in MongoDB official docs, but couldn't find it. Do you know if there is one? Thanks again.